# Is traverseBind a recognized FP concept?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I have a function `f: 'a -> Async<'b option>` that I want to call with `'a option` instead of `'a`. Now, if I had a function `g` that returned `Async<'b>` instead of `f`'s `Async<'b option>`, I could write a standard `traverse` implementation and I would then have `Async<'b option>` at the end. But if I use `traverse` with `f`, the result is `Async<'b option option>`.

It seems to me I need something like this:

```
module Option =

  let traverseBindAsync (f: 'a -> Async<'b option>) (opt: 'a option) : Async<'b option> =
    async {
      match opt with
      | None -> return None
      | Some x -> return! f x
    }
```

I don't think `traverseBind` is a recognized concept (no search results). Is it known under another name, or alternatively, is there another way to think about this in terms of recognized FP concepts one can express in F#? If so, could I use those concepts in a way that is more or less as syntactically concise as the above `Option.traverseBindAsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard name for a function of a type like this. However, there are two changes you can do to the code that might be somewhat revealing. First, you can implement it without the use of the `async` block, just by using either `f x` or by returning `async.Unit(None)`, i.e. an asynchronous computation that immediately returns `None`:

```
let traverseBindAsync (f: 'a -> Async<'b option>) (opt: 'a option) : Async<'b option> =
  match opt with
  | None -> async.Return None
  | Some x -> f x
```

Now you can also rewrite this as doing `Option.map` on the input and using `async.Return(None)` as the default value when the input option (and therefore also the result of the `map` operation) is `None`:

```
let traverseBindAsync (f: 'a -> Async<'b option>) (opt: 'a option) : Async<'b option> =
  opt |> Option.map f |> Option.defaultValue (async.Return None)
```

I don't think this has any name, but you can think of your function as `Option.map` with a particular default value when the input is not available.